# App.Run в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У метанита видел, как устанавливать куки, сделал следующим образом:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            string GuidId = "";
            if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("GuidId"))
            {
                 GuidId = context.Request.Cookies["GuidId"];
                 await context.Response.WriteAsync($"GuidId = {GuidId}") ;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("GuidId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                GuidId = context.Request.Cookies["GuidId"];
                await context.Response.WriteAsync($"GuidId = {GuidId}");
            }
        });
```

Но, как и ожидалось, при запуске просто показывает строчку с GuidId и всё. Хочу, чтобы мне показывалось представление Home/Index, или вызывался этот контроллер, но не понимаю, как правильно это сделать.

Comment: в каком случае?

Comment: @Grundy Да, забыл сказать. Вообще в любом случае. То есть, наверное, убрать два await, и после условия поставить другой, но я не знаю, что именно ставить после await для этого

Comment: попробуй просто убрать строки с `await` полностью

Comment: Тогда он показывает пустую страницу, и вылезает предупреждение 

"Предупреждение CS1998 - В данном асинхронном методе отсутствуют операторы await, поэтому метод будет выполняться синхронно. Воспользуйтесь оператором await для ожидания неблокирующих вызовов API или оператором await Task.Run(...) для выполнения связанных с ЦП заданий в фоновом потоке."

Если убрать async тоже, то будет ошибка

CS1643 - Не все ветви кода возвращают значение в лямбда-выражение типа RequestDelegate

Comment: @Grundy предупреждение правда не пропало, но, видимо надо было ставить App.Run после UseMvc, теперь понял, где ошибка. Но что-то можно с предупреждением сделать?

Comment: замени Run На Use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/write?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: предупреждение о чем?

Comment: С Use предупреждения нет и всё работает отлично! Спасибо!
Предупреждение было о том, что метод без await будет работать синхронно